# run python command line arguments in shell script

Tags: python, shell

I have a script which takes in few arguments

```
./hal --runtest=example
```

where `example = /home/user/example.py`

how can I pass these arguments in shell script?

Comment: Probably I don't understand at all your question, but, it looks like it is a shell scripting question, instead a python question.

Comment: You're going to have to help us by being more specific.

Comment: I don't mind if I don't get the "Best Answer" checkmark, but could you please give it to someone so this stops cluttering up the list of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking, but assuming your question is "How can a shell script pass dynamic arguments to a command that happens to be written in Python" and you are using a Bourne-family shell (very likely), the simplest correct answer would be

```
example=/home/user/example.py
./hal "--runtest=$example"
```

The shell will resolve the quoting and the script will see `--runtest=/home/user/example.py` without breaking if you later decide to pass in a path containing spaces.

Comment: Here are more details:

I have an automation framework written in python. It is executed from command line as ./hal --runtest=<testcase>

Now I created a .sh script under /etc/init.d which runs automatically after system reboot. This script when executed should 
execute /hal --runtest=<testcase> without any user intervention. I need a way to pass the arguments or execute the python script in the .sh script.

Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: You should really edit the question to add these details rather than replying in a comment (Q&A system, not forum).

Anyway, it seems my guess was correct, but I'm still not sure what specific problem you're having trouble solving.

Do you need to pass a shell variable to `--runtest` but not know how?
Are you having trouble getting the script to run at all from an initscript?
Is there some other problem I didn't guess?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to make sure you don't forget to mark an answer as the best answer and hand out "This answer is useful" (up arrow) clicks appropriately. As a new user, half my motivation is earning points. (The other half if me being obsessively nice) As you may have noticed, until we get 50 points, we can't even comment unless we're the questioner or the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the following:

http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-script-variables.html

It is Bash specific though and as per comments above not sure which shell you're using.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://docsrv.sco.com:507/en/OSUserG/_Passing_to_shell_script.html) you'll find all you need in terms of how to pass an argument to a shell script.